# SharedPreferences won't work

Tags: editor, sharedpreferences, commit

I have a problem with these SharedPreferences:

```
private String StringaCirc;
private StringBuffer StringAux;
```

[...]

```
public void stringaCirc(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        StringaCirc1.setCharAt(i, '0');
    StringaCirc=StringaCirc1.toString();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("StringaCirc", StringaCirc);
    editor.commit();
    }
```

But when i call the function the app crashes...What is the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the stacktrace? Also, I think you should call `getSharedPreferences()` not `getPreferences()`

Comment: `getPreferences()` are like `getSharedPreferences()` with a default key, that's not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't defined `StringaCirc1` in your method.

try to add this before for() loop

```
String StringaCirc1 = "";
```

you also should use lowercase first letters for your strings for readability

```
private String stringaCirc;
private StringBuffer stringAux;

[...]

public void stringaCirc() {
    String stringaCirc1 = "";
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        stringaCirc1.setCharAt(i, '0');
    stringaCirc = stringaCirc1.toString();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("StringaCirc", stringaCirc);
    editor.commit();
}
```